# Не запускаются скомпилированные программы на других компьютерах Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw

Всем доброго времени суток, написал программу на c++ и Qt в Qt Creator.
Компилировал через MinGW32 и MinGW64 под Windows. Дальше собрал все нужные файлы через windeployqt для каждой разрядности соответственно.

И появилась проблема что на тех ПК где в переменных среды не записан путь к компилятору выдает ошибку при попытке запуска. Ошибки либо просто числовой код, либо не обнаруживает библиотек. Версия  Qt 5.15.2.

Подскажите что я делаю не так и как правильно. Спасибо

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос сообщение об ошибке. Добавьте в вопрос параметры которые вы передавали `windeployqt`.

Comment: Я знаком с qt не очень хорошо, делал просто "перетаскиванием" файла *.exe на windeployqt. Скорее всего параметры по умолчанию запускались

Comment: Сталкивался с проблемой, что windeployqt собирает не все нужные файлы. Некоторые файлы приходилось искать и добавлять руками

Comment: Хм, а как он тогда при запуске на моем пк не выдает ошибки?

Comment: На вашем компьютере все необходимые библиотеки установлены вместе с Qt.

Comment: Посмотрите документацию по `windeployqt -static`. И всё это "перетаскивание" - не наш метод. Запускайте из командной строки, читайте документацию, пробуйте разные флаги.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов когда библиотеки все на месте он не видит точки входа в процедуру xxx. При том что путь к папке bin есть в переменной path

Comment: Для MinGW надо дополнительно подложить его библиотеки, windeployqt этого не делает

Comment: есть такая программка `depends`, показывает, чего не хватает

Comment: @Bearded Beaver спасибо сработало. Нашел в папке MinGW и закинул в папку проекта файлы на которые указывали ошибки. До этого пробовал просто скачивать по названию из нета.  Преобразуйте в ответ,  отмечу как решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Утилита windeployqt по каким-то причинам не умеет подкладывать библиотеки от самого MinGW, это надо сделать вручную. Они лежат в папке с бинарями Qt. В той версии, что использую я, нужно положить следующие файлы:

- `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`
- `libstdc++-6.dll`
- `libwinpthread-1.dll`